# Invalid anonymous type member declerator when joining a field with a static value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a join clause with multiple conditions, one being a static value, however I'm receiving "Invalid anonymous type member declerator" when compiling.

```
join t7 in db.Notes.DefaultIfEmpty() on new { t2.Lead_ID } equals new { t7.Item_ID, 5 = t7.Type_ID } into notes
```

For clarity, I'm joining:

- t2.Lead_ID to t7.Item_ID
- t7.Type_ID to 5 (or a variable)

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why are you trying to assign t7.Type_ID to the literal value 5? That itself is a compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this wrong. From you code it seems, you try to join on object that have one prop on one side and object with 2 props on the other (and 5= t7.Item_ID) is an error itself.
You should try writing it like this:

```
join t7 in db.Notes.DefaultIfEmpty() on t2.Lead_ID equals t7.Item_ID into notes
where t7.Item_ID == 5
```

This should give you result you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the same number of parameters on both sides of your `equals`, and they need to have the same name.

```
join t7 in db.Notes.DefaultIfEmpty()
    on new { Item_ID = t2.Lead_ID, Type_ID = 5 } equals new { t7.Item_ID, t7.Type_ID }
    into notes
```

See [How to: Join by Using Composite Keys (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907099.aspx)

> If the properties in the source sequences do not have the same names, you must assign new names in the keys.